# Providing tensor input using tf.keras.layers.Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, bert-language-model

I am trying to perform a multiclass classification using a simple BERT model. I am referring to the following tutorial for help: [tensorflow classification tutorial with bert](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert).

I use the following code to create the tensor from a pandas dataframe:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df_train['OriginalTweet'], df_train['labels']))
train_ds_renamed = train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: {'input':x, 'label':y})
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df_val['OriginalTweet'], df_val['labels']))
val_ds_renamed = val_dataset.map(lambda x, y: {'input':x, 'label':y})
```

```
for row in train_ds_renamed.take(3):
    print(row)

Output:
{'input': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'@MeNyrbie @Phil_Gahan @Chrisitv'>, 'label': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>}
{'input': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'advice Talk to your neighbours family to exchange phone numbers create contact list with phone numbers of neighbours schools employer chemist GP set up online shopping accounts if poss adequate supplies of regular meds but not over order'>, 'label': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1>}
{'input': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'Coronavirus Australia: Woolworths to give elderly, disabled dedicated shopping hours amid COVID-19 outbreak '>, 'label': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1>}
```

Then I tried implementing the model:

```
def build_classifier_model():
    text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), tensor=tensor_type[0], name='input')
    preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, name='preprocessing')
    encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
    encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
    outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
    net = outputs['pooled_output']
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None, name='classifier')(net)
    return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)
```

```
classifier_model = build_classifier_model()
```

```
epochs = 5
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

classifier_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss, metrics='accuracy')
```

But when i try to train the model by running the following block of code:

```
print(f'Training model with {tfhub_handle_encoder}')

history = classifier_model.fit(x=train_ds_renamed,
                               validation_data=val_ds_renamed,
                               epochs=epochs)
```

I get the following error:

```
raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
        * False
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
    
    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='sentences')
        * False
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 2:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='sentences')
        * True
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 3:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='inputs')
        * False
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 4:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='inputs')
        * True
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
```

I do not understand why is this happening because from what I can understand the input shape() and and dtype is the same as expected shape() and dtype

Answer (score 1):

The input is supposed to be `tf.string`, not python string.